# How to get the area string from a polygon using leaflet.draw

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to get the area measurements of polygons so I can list them in a table to the side of the map, next to the name of the polygon.  This is what I have tried with no success:

```
$("#polygon").on("click", function (){
    createPolygon = new L.Draw.Polygon(map, drawControl.options.polygon);
    createPolygon.enable();
}

var polygon = new L.featureGroup();

map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
    var type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;
    if (type === 'polygon') {
      polygons.addLayer(layer);
    }
    var seeArea = createPolygon._getMeasurementString();
   console.log(seeArea);  //Returns null
}
```

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Comment: may you add a fiddle pls ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can access the geometry utility library provided with Leaflet.

```
var area = L.GeometryUtil.geodesicArea(layer.getLatLngs());
```

In your example, you are trying to access a control itself, which is what the variable createPolygon is assigned to. Instead, you want to take the area of the layer that got drawn.

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
  var type = e.layerType,
      layer = e.layer;
  if (type === 'polygon') {
    polygons.addLayer(layer);
    var seeArea = L.GeometryUtil.geodesicArea(layer.getLatLngs());
    console.log(seeArea);
  }
}
```

Once you verify you are getting the area, you can just assign it to the variables that populate the table next to the map.

Note: area will be in squareMeters by default

Comment: Please note that the geometry utility library here refers to the: [Leaflet.draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw).

Comment: this doesn't work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60827549/274677

Comment: I keep getting area = 0

Comment: You need to access to first position of getLatLngs result:

`let seeArea = L.GeometryUtil.geodesicArea(layer.getLatLngs()[0]);`

Comment: Yes.
As the `layer.getLatLngs()` is a nested array, so we need to get the first position `layer.getLatLngs()[0]`

Answer (score 4):

`L.GeometryUtil.geodesicArea(layer.getLatLngs())[0]` should get you the area.

But I ended up using `leaflet-geoman-free` to do the drawing and use `turf.js` to get the area.

```
map.pm.enableDraw('Polygon', {
   snappable: true,
   snapDistance: 20,
});

map.on('pm:create', e => {
   const layer = e.layer
   alert(turf.area(layer.toGeoJSON()))
});
```

Answer (score 3):

add corrections:

```
var seeArea = L.GeometryUtil.geodesicArea(layer.getLatLngs()[0]);
console.log(seeArea);
```

Answer (score 3):

I found that none of the above answers worked for calculating the area of *non-contiguous* polygons. Here's an example polygon where the above functions returned an area of 0:

[image: Non-contiguous Polygon]

For anyone who needs to do that, here is the code that worked for me (using the `L.GeometryUtil` function from Leaflet.draw):

```js
var poly = // Your polygon layer here; may or may not be contiguous
var area = 0;
for (island of poly.getLatLngs()) {
    // If the polygon is non-contiguous, access the island
    if (island.length < 2) {
        island = island[0]
    }
    // Sum the area within each "island"
    area += L.GeometryUtil.geodesicArea(island);
}
```