# Leaflet Js computing area of GeoJSON multipolygon

Tags: leaflet, geojson

This is realted to this question:

[How to get the area string from a polygon using leaflet.draw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29724725/how-to-get-the-area-string-from-a-polygon-using-leaflet-draw)

The area calculation works for Polygons, not for multipolygons, any idea on a feature that calculates the area of such GeoJSON Feature?

As a workaround, I can transform the multipolygon into polygons, but it's not an ideal solution.

Many thanks,
VG.

Comment: found the answer, var area = LGeo.area(myLayer); and it requres the leaflet-geodesy plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use [Turf.js](http://turfjs.org/) for these kind of tasks.

Comment: thanks for the great suggestion, will look into this too.

Answer (score 1):

[Leaflet.PM](https://github.com/codeofsumit/leaflet.pm) supports editing and cutting of MultiPolygons.
Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [@turf/area](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@turf/area), which can compute area of polygons and multipolygons.