# GeometryUtil.geodesicArea() returning massive values

Tags: geometry, leaflet, geospatial, leaflet.draw

I'm binding a popup to my polygons containing information about the area of the polygon, using the GeometryUtil.geodesicArea function.  Here it is, pasted [straight from the code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/blob/develop/src/ext/GeometryUtil.js):

```
geodesicArea: function (latLngs) {
        var pointsCount = latLngs.length,
            area = 0.0,
            d2r = Math.PI / 180,
            p1, p2;

        if (pointsCount > 2) {
            for (var i = 0; i < pointsCount; i++) {
                p1 = latLngs[i];
                p2 = latLngs[(i + 1) % pointsCount];
                area += ((p2.lng - p1.lng) * d2r) *
                    (2 + Math.sin(p1.lat * d2r) + Math.sin(p2.lat * d2r));
            }
            area = area * 6378137.0 * 6378137.0 / 2.0;
        }

        return Math.abs(area);
    }
```

When I draw a rectangle over the approximate area of Saskatchewan, Canada, using these coordinates:

```
0: {lat: 49.06465160956338, lng: -110.00904901708327}
1: {lat: 59.94790491663552, lng: -110.00904901708327}
2: {lat: 59.94790491663552, lng: -101.6155500597509}
3: {lat: 49.06465160956338, lng: -101.6155500597509}
```

[roughly 651,900 sq km](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saskatchewan), it is returning 30610232650154772. If this number is [assumed to be in square meters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29813099/11187867), it is to equal to roughly 30 billion square kilometers, [which is well beyond the surface area of the entire earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth), unless I'm missing something about what the meaning is of the numbers being returned.

What does this geodesic area function calculate? Is there some other way/function I should be using to get the area of a polygon?

Here is the code I'm using as well as calculated values line-by-line
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the brackets in

area + = (p2.lng - p1.lng * d2r) *

necessary:

area + = ((p2.lng - p1.lng) * d2r) *

Answer (score 0):

Just use Heron's formula and L.GeometryUtil.length() to achieve this:
[Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula)