# how to calculate area of polygon using Leaflet.Draw GeometryUtil

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29813099/274677) on how to calculate the area of a polygon and I am trying to achieve the same. However, I consistently get 0 (zero) for the area.

JS fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mperdikeas/v8rty76d/1/).
The crux of my code is:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([19.04469, 72.9258], 12).addLayer(osm);
var latlngs = [[19.04469, 72.9258], [19.07459, 72.9358], [19.08469, 72.4758]];
var polygon = L.polygon(latlngs, {color: 'red'}).addTo(map);
console.log('area is: '+L.GeometryUtil.geodesi
```

I consistently get `area is: 0` on the console.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `.getLatLngs()` see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uhzL79wt/1/)

```
L.GeometryUtil.geodesicArea(polygon.getLatLngs()));
```