# I´m stucked creating Leaflet buttons on ngx-leaflet

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet, ngx-leaflet

I´m completly stucked in Angular project with `leaflet and ngx-leaflet` right now and this is what happens.

I´ve created some custom `leaflet controls` like this `div`:

[Toolbar example][image]

The problem is the next one; I´ve created this `div` as a `custom leaflet control`like this into the `onReady(){}`:

```
L.Control.Barra = L.Control.extend({
  options: {
    position: 'topright',
  },
  onAdd: function (mapa) {
    let contenedor = L.DomUtil.create(
      'div',
      'col mx-auto leaflet-bar leaflet-control barra'
    );
    contenedor.id = 'barra';
    L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(contenedor);

    let bPrueba = L.DomUtil.create(
      'button',
      'm-2 btn btn-secondary',
      contenedor
    );
    bPrueba.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-list"></i>';
    bPrueba.title = 'Listado';
    let bPrueba2 = L.DomUtil.create(
      'button',
      'm-2 btn btn-secondary',
      contenedor
    );
    bPrueba2.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-palette"></i>';
    bPrueba2.title = 'Categorizar';
    let bPrueba3 = L.DomUtil.create(
      'button',
      'm-2 btn btn-secondary',
      contenedor
    );
    bPrueba3.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-chart-pie"></i>';
    bPrueba3.title = 'Análisis';
    let bPrueba4 = L.DomUtil.create(
      'button',
      'm-2 btn btn-secondary',
      contenedor
    );
    bPrueba4.innerHTML = '<i class="far fa-chart-bar"></i>';
    bPrueba4.title = 'Análisis potencia proyecto';
    let bPrueba5 = L.DomUtil.create(
      'button',
      'm-2 btn btn-secondary',
      contenedor
    );
    bPrueba5.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-chart-area"></i>';
    bPrueba5.title = 'Análisis potencia visible';
    let bPrueba6 = L.DomUtil.create(
      'button',
      'm-2 btn btn-secondary',
      contenedor
    );
    bPrueba6.innerHTML = '<i class="far fa-file"></i>';
    bPrueba6.title = 'Fichas';
    let bPrueba7 = L.DomUtil.create(
      'button',
      'm-2 btn btn-secondary',
      contenedor
    );
    bPrueba7.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-street-view"></i>';
    bPrueba7.title = 'Street view';
    let bPrueba8 = L.DomUtil.create(
      'button',
      'm-2 btn btn-secondary',
      contenedor
    );
    bPrueba8.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-ruler-combined"></i>';
    bPrueba8.title = 'Medir area';
    let bPrueba9 = L.DomUtil.create(
      'button',
      'm-2 btn btn-secondary',
      contenedor
    );
    bPrueba9.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-ruler"></i>';
    bPrueba9.title = 'Medir línea';
    let bPrueba10 = L.DomUtil.create(
      'button',
      'm-2 btn btn-secondary',
      contenedor
    );
    bPrueba10.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-print"></i>';
    bPrueba10.title = 'Imprimir';
    let bPrueba11 = L.DomUtil.create(
      'button',
      'm-2 btn btn-secondary',
      contenedor
    );
    bPrueba11.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-file-upload"></i>';
    bPrueba11.title = 'Cargar WMS';
    let bPrueba12 = L.DomUtil.create(
      'button',
      'm-2 btn btn-secondary',
      contenedor
    );
    bPrueba12.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-file-export"></i>';
    bPrueba12.title = 'Descargar';

    contenedor.title = 'Barra';
    return contenedor;
  },
  onRemove: function (mapa) {},
});
let prueba = new L.Control.Barra();
prueba.addTo(mapa);
```

I wish to add to this buttons the functions of drawing but don´t know how to do it, I´ve read a lot of stack overflow posts, internet forums post and for sure, the API docs of `leaflet`, `leaflet-draw`, `ngx-leaflet` and `ngx-leaflet-draw`.

I´m pretty newbie on stack overflow so if it´s something wrong in the post, say it to me for make corrections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easy add click events to the buttons with [L.DomEvent](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#domevent-on):

```
L.DomEvent.on(bPrueba, 'click', function(e){console.log(e)});
```

also you can call a method of the control:

```
L.Control.Barra = L.Control.extend({
  options: {
    position: 'topright',
  },
  onAdd: function (mapa) {
    let contenedor = L.DomUtil.create(
      'div',
      'col mx-auto leaflet-bar leaflet-control barra'
    );
    contenedor.id = 'barra';
    L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(contenedor);

    let bPrueba = L.DomUtil.create(
      'button',
      'm-2 btn btn-secondary',
      contenedor
    );
    bPrueba.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-list"></i>';
    bPrueba.title = 'Listado';


    L.DomEvent.on(bPrueba, 'click', this.clickFunc1); // <------------

    //....
  },
  clickFunc1: function(e){
      console.log(e);
  }
});
```

To start a draw function call:

```
new L.Draw.Polyline(map).enable();
```

so for you:

```
clickFunc1: function(e){
      new L.Draw.Polyline(map).enable();
  }
```

But I prefer [Leaflet-Geoman](https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman) there you can simply call `map.pm.enableDraw('Polyline')` with a lot of function and it has a newer design.

Comment: The fact is that I can use on the Draw events on them? @FalkeDesign

Comment: I don't understand your comment... You want to use draw events? like `draw:created`? Or do you want to start to draw?

Comment: I will try my best to explain it, some of this buttons have to draw, one of them is for drawing a free polygon until I make double click and get the whole polygon area and other one which have to get in KM the full poligon line distance. 

I have in my mind more or less how to do it but I can´t co-relate the `draw` funcitons to this buttons. @FalkeDesign

Comment: Okey, I will try and I will comment the result @falkeDesign

Comment: it works! I need to make some adjusts but works properly!

Comment: Hello again @falkeDesign, thanks so much for answer me, it´s always nice to recive help when someone is stucked, I only have a little doubt. I want to get the area of the polygon, ¿Is it possible?

Comment: You can use L.GeometryUtil https://stackoverflow.com/a/62515584/8283938

Comment: at the end, I´ve found a way with the own shape properties, thanks you!